# How to scroll in to focused textbox in android + phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am using PhoneGap (Cordovar 2.5) and jQuery Mobile 1.3.0. On iOS, whenever I focus on a text box, the keyboard shows and push up the page, but on Android it doesn't. I have tried to use `android:windowSoftInputMode=""` but no success. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android does not correctly scroll on input focus if not body element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757345/android-does-not-correctly-scroll-on-input-focus-if-not-body-element)

Answer (score 1):

In any part of you app (js file, of course) pus this script:

```
if(/Android 4\.[0-3]/.test(navigator.appVersion)){
   window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
      if(document.activeElement.tagName=="INPUT"){
         window.setTimeout(function(){
            document.activeElement.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
         },0);
      }
   })
}
```

The answer was in: [Android does not correctly scroll on input focus if not body element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757345/android-does-not-correctly-scroll-on-input-focus-if-not-body-element)