# How to avoid an input field becoming hidden when a keyboard is up on Android Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, input, hidden

Is there a way to automatically scroll down on a webpage, when a certain input field becomes hidden due to Android keyboard on Chrome for Android? I know how to scroll a webpage using JavaScript, but has someone tried to do it for this specific purpose?

Comment: Topic is discussed in detail Here
[https://stackoverflow.com/q/23757345/2477472](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23757345/2477472)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android does not correctly scroll on input focus if not body element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757345/android-does-not-correctly-scroll-on-input-focus-if-not-body-element)